# Getting only the very last element in a table rather than the complete resultset with PHP and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to get data from a database using PHP and PDO, here it is a snippet from my code:

```
$query = $this->dbconn->get_db_access()->prepare("SELECT id from blog_posts ORDER BY pub_date DESC LIMIT :s, :l");
$query->bindParam(":s", $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->bindParam(":l", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result);
return $result;
```

and the `print_r` output is `Array ( [id] => 3 )`, the last id of the row I inserted. On the other hand if I execute

`SELECT id from blog_posts ORDER BY pub_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20;`

I get the correct result `1,2,3`. So what is wrong with my PDO code? Why don't I get the complete resultset in return, but only the very last id in the table?

Comment: What's the value of `$start` and `$limit`?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos 0 and 20 respectively

Comment: `$query->fetch()` only returns 1 element, use `$query->fetchAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$query->fetch();` will return one element

use `$query->fetchAll()`

Answer (score 0):

```
result = $query->fetchAll();
```